# kern.log reports times in UTC instead of local time zone

Tags: kernel, system, time

I attempted to set my local timezone to `America/New_York` by doing (as root):

```
# cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
# echo "America/New_York" > /etc/timezone
# dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

The "date" program reports the right time zone:

```
$ date 
Thu Feb 14 16:51:28 EST 2013
```

However, /var/log/kern.log is still reporting times in UTC, e.g.:

```
Feb 14 21:38:28 newyork kernel: [39716989.760755]  xvdf: unknown partition table
```

Do I need to reboot to fix this? or is there something else I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to reboot, just make sure to restart cron and rsyslog so they pick up the new timezone.

```
sudo service cron restart
sudo service rsyslog restart
```